# Combine elements of 1 array to create a new array using a for-loop

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop

Good afternoon all,

I'm assigned a programming problem where I need to take a single array with a various number of elements, and configure a new array.

The new array will be composed of the first two element's sum, followed by the next two elements sum, so on and so forth.

If the original array has an odd number of elements, the last value will remain the same, with the summation values preceding.

```
public static int[] collapse(int[] old) {
    int[] nNew = new int[old.length];        
    if(old.length%2 == 0){
        nNew = new int[old.length/2];    
        for(int i =0; i<nNew.length; i+=2) {                        
            int temp = old[i] + old[i+1];
            nNew[i] = temp;            
        }                   
    }
     //i tried to for loop to increment by 1 here, but it didn't work out.
     //I believe this is where my problem is.

    if(old.length%2 != 0) {
        nNew = new int[(old.length/2) +1];        
        for(int i =0; i<nNew.length-1; i++) {
            //I can't get an Odd number of array elements to increment by 2
            int temp = old[i] + old[i+1];
            nNew[i] = temp;
            nNew[nNew.length-1] = old[old.length-1];
        }                
    }    
    return nNew; 
}
```

Example calls include:

```
collapse({7, 2, 8, 9, 4, 13, 7, 1, 9, 10}) 
expected: {9, 17, 17, 8, 19}
my result: {9, 0, 17, 0, 17}

collapse({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) 
expected: {3, 7, 5} 
my result: {3, 5, 5}
```

Comment: `i++`should be `i+=2`.  Also move `nNew[nNew.length-1] = old[old.length-1];` outside of the loop.

Comment: Those two suggestions worked for everything else besides the two examples calls. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, actually, you're indexing on the new array, so `old[i]`  index should be `2*i` and `old[i+1]` index should be `2*i+1`, and for loop index should increment by one `i++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for separate loops. Just check within the same loop:

```
public static int[] collapse(int[] old) {
    int[] nNew = new int[(old.length + 1) / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < old.length; i += 2) {
        nNew[i / 2] = old[i];
        if (i + 1 < old.length) {
            nNew[i / 2] += old[i + 1];
        }
    }
    return nNew;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your issue with the odd length array, you could start your for loop at 1, and then instead of looking at the current and next value, you would look at i-1 and i, and then increment by 2. That would be able to stop the error you have with an index.OutofBounds error.

Example :

```
if(old.length%2 != 0) {
    nNew = new int[(old.length/2) +1];        
    for(int i =1; i<nNew.length-1; i += 2) {
        //I can't get an Odd number of array elements to increment by 2
        int temp = old[i-1] + old[i];
        nNew[i] = temp;
        nNew[nNew.length-1] = old[old.length-1];
    }                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this is using one for loop und if statement to help in case array length is old number that mean the last number will not appear so you just have to add it yourself.

```
public static int[] collapse(int[] array) {
    int[] newArray = new int[(array.length + 1)/2];
    int lastnum = array[array.length-1];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i += 2) {
        newArray[i/2] = array[i] + array[i-1];
    }
    if (newArray[newArray.length-1] == 0)newArray[newArray.length-1] = lastnum;
    return newArray;
}
```